# How to pass parameter to an anonymous function defined in the setTimeout call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
function addRcd2(timeOut){  
  for(var c=0; c less 5; c++){
    var rcdi = "rcd_"+c+"";
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('.tbl1 tbody').append(rcdi);
    },timeOut*c);
  }
}
```

The output of this code is a table which rows have the same text `rcd_5`.

My goal is to have a table rows have different records `rcd_1`, …, `rcd_5`.

Any ideas?

Comment: That code should work.  I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: No it wont, it's a common closure mistake

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typical *creating a function in a loop* problem. All closures you pass to `setTimeout` have a reference to the **same** `rcdi` variable. Defining the variable inside the loop is the same as defining it outside:

```
var rcdi;
for(var c=0; c < 5; c++){
    rcdi = "rcd_"+c+"";
    // ...
}
```

which makes it a bit more apparent that you only deal with *one* variable here.

You have to introduce a new scope, which in JavaScript can only be achieved through functions:

```
function getCallback(val) {
    return function(){
      $('.tbl1 tbody').append(val);
    };
}

function addRcd2(timeOut){  
  for(var c=0; c < 5; c++){
    setTimeout(getCallback("rcd_"+c),timeOut*c);
  }
}
```

As you can see in other answers, you can also use *immediate functions*. Use what you find more readable.

Answer (score 2):

```
function addRcd2(timeOut){  
  for(var c=0; c less 5; c++){
    var rcdi = "rcd_"+c+"";
    setTimeout((function(x) {
      return function(){
        $('.tbl1 tbody').append(x);
      };
    })(rcdi),timeOut*c);
  }
}
```