# Functions within a loop using requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, requirejs

I'm having an issue with calling functions within a loop across different modules using requirejs. The function call within the loop resides in module A and executes a function in module B that fires off an Ajax request using jQuery. Each iteration of the loop fires off a different request with different arguments being passed to module B's function that fires off the Ajax request. When the success function of the Ajax request executes, I find that all my argument values are always the values of the last Ajax call made, for all 4 separate Ajax calls.

I've done some googling and it sounds like this is a pretty common problem when executing a function within a loop. The fix tends to be to break out the function call into a different function, creating a different scope. Since my loop and Ajax calls are in 2 different modules I had assumed this would solve that issue, however it still persists.

I've tried some solutions in other stack overflow posts like: 
[JSlint error 'Don't make functions within a loop.' leads to question about Javascript itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927054/jslint-error-dont-make-functions-within-a-loop-leads-to-question-about-javas) and [How to pass parameter to an anonymous function defined in the setTimeout call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396121/how-to-pass-parameter-to-an-anonymous-function-defined-in-the-settimeout-call) without success. Anyone have any idea?

Sample code for loop module A:

```
define(["mpos"],
    function(mpos){

        var monitor = {
            startMonitoring : function(poolObj){    
                // Start Monitoring
                $.each(mpos.msgs, function(action,callback){
                    poolObj.action = action;
                    mpos.sendApiRequest(poolObj,action,callback);

                });
            }
        };

        return monitor;
    }
);
```

Sample code for Ajax module B - this module is referenced as mpos in module A

```
define(["mule","constants"],
function(mule,constants){

    var mpos = {
        sendMessage : function(postData,callback,$poolOut){

            return $.ajax({
                'type':'post',
                'url':constants.URLS.proxy,
                'data':{'url':postData},
                success : function(data){
                    // if we have $poolOut we know this is a mpos call
                    if($poolOut != undefined){
                        var keys = Object.keys(data);
                        // add poolOut to data
                        data.poolOut = $poolOut;

                        var poolObj = $poolOut.data('poolObj');
                        if(poolObj){
                            var action = poolObj.action;
                            console.log(poolObj,action);
                            if(action){
                                if(action == "getuserstatus"){
                                    mule.registerPool(poolObj);
                                }
                            } else {
                                log.error("No action on poolObj while attempting to calculate the need for a registerPool call");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // parse data
                    callback.apply(this, data);
                },
                error : function(x,h,r){ ... },
                dataType : 'json'
            });
        },
        sendApiRequest : function(poolObj,action,callback){
            var url = poolObj.url + '&page=api&action=' + action;

            var $poolOut = constants.cache.monitorOutput.find('.pool-out.' + poolObj.id);

            var dfd = mpos.sendMessage(url,callback,$poolOut);

            $.when(dfd).always(function(){
                var refreshTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                    if(constants.state.monitorEnabled){
                        mpos.sendApiRequest(poolObj, action, callback);
                    }
                }, poolObj.refreshRate);

            });
        },
        msgs : {
            "getuserstatus" : function(data){ ... },
            "getpoolstatus" : function(data){ ... },
            "getuserworkers" : function(data){ ... },
            "getuserbalance" : function(data){ ... }
        }
    };

    return mpos;
}
);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to copy your non-working code under the same module? I guess the problem is with your code, not with the requirejs, but maybe I am wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: I am assuming that `$poolOut.data('poolObj')` is being used to find the `poolObj` instance passed in the call to `startMonitoring`, and will return the same instance each time.

You state, "Each iteration of the loop fires off a different request with different arguments being passed to module B's function that fires off the Ajax request."

This statement is not correct.  Each iteration fires off a different request with the first argument `poolObj` being the *same* in each iteration.

In your `.each` iteration, you are overwriting the value of `poolObj.action` before each call to `sendApiRequest`.

In the AJAX success handler, which is likely invoked *after* all iterations have completed, the value of `poolObj.action` will have the value you set it to in the last iteration.

To solve this, I think you need to pass `action` as a parameter to `sendMessage`, too, so that a separate value is being stored in the closure for each function call.

```
var mpos = {
    sendMessage : function(postData,action,callback,$poolOut){

        return $.ajax({
            'type':'post',
            'url':constants.URLS.proxy,
            'data':{'url':postData},
            success : function(data){
                // if we have $poolOut we know this is a mpos call
                if($poolOut != undefined){
                    var keys = Object.keys(data);
                    // add poolOut to data
                    data.poolOut = $poolOut;

                    var poolObj = $poolOut.data('poolObj');
                    if(poolObj){
                        // action is not guaranteed to be the same as poolObj.action here,
                        // since poolObj.action may have changed since this function was first called
                        console.log(poolObj,action);
                        if(action){
                            if(action == "getuserstatus"){
                                mule.registerPool(poolObj);
                            }
                        } else {
                            log.error("No action on poolObj while attempting to calculate the need for a registerPool call");
                        }
                    }
                }
                // parse data
                callback.apply(this, data);
            },
            error : function(x,h,r){ ... },
            dataType : 'json'
        });
    },
    sendApiRequest : function(poolObj,action,callback){
        var url = poolObj.url + '&page=api&action=' + action;

        var $poolOut = constants.cache.monitorOutput.find('.pool-out.' + poolObj.id);

        var dfd = mpos.sendMessage(url,action,callback,$poolOut);

        $.when(dfd).always(function(){
            var refreshTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                if(constants.state.monitorEnabled){
                    mpos.sendApiRequest(poolObj, action, callback);
                }
            }, poolObj.refreshRate);

        });
    },
    msgs : {
        "getuserstatus" : function(data){ ... },
        "getpoolstatus" : function(data){ ... },
        "getuserworkers" : function(data){ ... },
        "getuserbalance" : function(data){ ... }
    }
};
```

Comment: Yep, I had a massive logic issue here. Trying to reuse the same obj for each iteration as if it was a new obj. Not sure how I missed this for hrs and hrs. Thanks for you input, helped a ton!