# Why each oo function/module after ajax, then each function/module attribute change to the last execute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oop, requirejs

I tried to sync database return html string append to each `.buttonContainer` , use action.js execute other file `loadButton` module use parameter point specific element.
the result should be use different `.buttonContainer` and with their attr id connect db get result append to each `.buttonContainer`

My question is if I set ajax option async default `true`, then both return html string will append to the last `.buttonContainer`.
I can't understand I already set each module/function have their attr `el` from each execute parameter.
Why and how to solve it?
I tried to change async to false then it work but slowly the page, so I'm trying to find other solution.

```
<div class="buttonContainer" data-user-id="0"></div>
<div class="buttonContainer" data-user-id="1"></div>
```

action.js

```
define(['DomReady!', 'jquery', 'loadButton'],function (DomReady, $, loadButton) {
  return {
    init: function() {
      // loop each element as parameter and execute 
      $('.buttonContainer').each(function(index, el) {
        var config = {};
        config.el = $(this);

        loadButton.init(config);
      });
    },
  }
});
```

loadButton.js

```
define(['DomReady!', 'jquery'],function (DomReady, $) {
  return {
    init: function(config) {
      this.config = {};
      this.config.el = config.el;  // set each execute have their own private attribute

      this.onLoadAction();
    },
    onLoadAction: function() {
      this.onLoadController();
    },
    onLoadController: function() {
      var userId = this.config.el.attr('data-user-id');

      var mthis = this;
      this.onLoadRequestDB('load/'+userId).done(function(response) {
        console.log(mthis.config.el);
        var response = JSON.parse(response);
        mthis.config.el.append(response.button);
      });
    },
    onLoadRequestDB: function(url) {
      return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        // async: false
      });
    },
  }
});
```

Edit:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22121078/1775888 I found some solution here, so I edit loadButton.js like this

```
..
init: function(config) {
          this.config = {};
          this.config.el = config.el;  // set each execute have their own private attribute

          this.onLoadAction(this.config);
        },
        onLoadAction: function(config) {
          this.onLoadController(config);
        },
        onLoadController: function(config) {
 ..
```

pass parameter, then it work.
But I still want to know why I set the loadButton.js init `this`, in each loop  but still can be cover after ajax. makes all response append to element from last execute `loadButton.js` `config` parameter

Comment: What do you think how many `loadButton`, `loadButton.config` and `loadButton.config.el`s you have?

Comment: ?? a lots and I tried to make function reusable , I can just pass the specific element the return html to append

Comment: What should your (singleton!) `loadButton` object represent? What's its purpose?

Comment: ?? I'm not understand what you mean?

Comment: Did you ask what is `loadButton` do?  I hope it can be use the element from outside inject(`config` parameter), then get the element data attribute unique id send to server,  append response back  to the element from outside inject(`config` parameter).   So I expect each time `loadButton.js` execute, the element inside the function should be base on inject from `config` parameter.  But my problem is I can't understand why `loadButton.js` after execute ajax then will append all response to the last execute `loadButton.js` parament element?

Comment: Because `loadButton.js` is only executed once, and you call `.init(…)` multiple times on the *same object*!

Comment: really?? why? I call it in a loop  and I did test if I put console.log `this.config.el` before ajax then it will show el as same during the loop, not point to the same one

Comment: Because modules (script files) are loaded only once! All you do is calling `loadButton.init(…)` in a loop. There aren't multiple `loadButton` objects created anywhere.